# Could not find generator rspec:install (q2)

Tags: rspec

I'm trying to follow this tutorial here: http://railstutorial.org/chapters/static-pages#top

When I run:

> $ rails generate rspec:install

I get:

> **Could not find generator rspec:install.**

What could be the problem?

[Rails 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

Thanks.

Answer (score 89):

Add to your Gemfile:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
end
```

and run **bundle install**

make sure that it is in **both the :development and :test blocks**. If you inadvertently put it *only in the :test block*, it will give the error above (that's because by default you're running in the `development` environment and rspec ins't available to that environment).

`rails generate rspec:install` should then run as expected.

Comment: This wasn't working for me until I figured out that I was doing "rails generate rspec::install" (with two colons), instead of "rails generate rspec:install" (with just one like you're supposed to.) If, like me, you're new to ruby and this doesn't work, check your syntax.

Comment: not sure it installed nokogiri, but installation of 'spec-rails' solves the issue

Comment: Note: version number is optional

Comment: edited answer to clarify this is most commonly because you forget to add it to :development block (only adding it to :test); also removed the previous gem version number as it does not add usefulness to answer -J

Answer (score 29):

Make sure you install `rspec-rails` and not only `rspec`. Sigh, I lost some time.

Comment: I found myself simply not having rspec in gemfile

Comment: I had to also `gem uninstall rspec` if it was in my Gem library

Answer (score 6):

If you, like me, created a project, decided you wanted to archive the old directory and start again, but left `spring` running in the background on accident, `spring` won't reload from the correct directory and you'll be very confused.

The solution is to stop spring and let it restart on its own.

Answer (score 4):

I had do both `gem install rspec` and then add to gemfile as Andreas said.

using Rails 3.2.1 and ruby 1.9.3 at windows 7 and worked perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

Remove all rspec versions by running the following commands as suggested by Sydney in another post and then install -V 2.0.1

```
gem uninstall rspec
gem uninstall rspec-core rspec-expectations rspec-mocks rspec-support
gem install rspec -v 2.0.1
```

add the following line to the gem file

```
gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 2.0.0'
```

and then run

```
rails generate rspec:install
```

it runs without any issues

Answer (score 2):

I got this same error and found that i had forgotten to save the Gemfile changes I made in Sublime prior to running the Bundle install command.  I saved and then reran the bundle install and was able to run the rails generate rspec:install command

Comment: Worth noting this answer. I did the same mistake. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Add `gem 'rspec-rails'` in `Gemfile` and save it. Run `bundle` command in Terminal. And in `config/application.rb`, add this line of configuration

```
config.generators do |g|
  g.test_framework   :rspec, :fixture => true, :views => false
  g.integration_tool :rspec, :fixture => true, :views => true
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Restart spring - sometimes it fails to reload after running bundle.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing it as a gem.

gem install rspec

with rails 3 in your config/environment.rb you maintain gems there with bundle install but in terms of what your doing you can just gem install rspec.

Answer (score 1):

Restart spring - sometimes it fails to reload after running bundle. To stop spring you can use `bin/spring stop`. It should start automatically when you run rails commands.

Comment: I just closed and opened a new terminal (following the addition of the gem and running `bundle`) and then the rspec generators were available. I guess spring not reloading was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that I had not saved after I updated my `Gemfile`. I simply saved, ran `bundle install` on the command line, and finally ran `$ rails generate rspec:install`

Answer (score 0):

By default I had only `'rspec-rails'` in my gemfile, and so bundler installed rspec-rails 1.x (some prehistoric version) for some reason. After I modified my gemfile to have `gem 'rspec-rails', '~>3.0'` and ran bundle update it ran fine.