# Could not find generator rspec:install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm running ruby 1.8.7 and rails 3.0.3. And I can't get rspec installed.

My Gemfile contains the following:

```
group :test, :development do
  gem "rspec-rails", "~> 2.4"
end
```

But I there is no rspec:install generator after bundle install.
I've tried the various answers around the net, setting rspec-rails to the 2.0.0.beta.22, 2.3.1, 2.3.0 and so on, but nothing seems to work.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to get the rspec:install generator?

Thanks

Lars

Comment: Maybe it can't find rspec? Does `rspec -v` work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not find generator rspec:install (q2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426406/could-not-find-generator-rspecinstall-q2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure you have RSpec installed within your development environment.
Have a look here for the correct way to get RSpec installed and running.

https://github.com/dchelimsky/rspec/wiki/rails

Answer (score 0):

update bundler, gem update should get it.

Answer (score 0):

Also [check rspec-rails github page](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails) for Rails 3.